# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
why iam getting this issue. my requirement is to run my selenium script with my windows installed chrome browser.can any one please help me out

iam using this below code for opening browser, when ran the code it's successfully opening my local windows chrome browser, for that next step entering url it's failing and it's giving the above issue

```
ChromeOptions o=new ChromeOptions();
        o.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\Hemadri Reddy\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\User Data");
        o.setBrowserVersion("120.0.6099.71");
        WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver(o);
        d.get("https://tester.com");
```

i updated my selenium dependency with 4.12.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLi7.png)

i wanted to run my selenium script with my local windows chrome browser

Comment: looks like the path for user-data-dir is wrong (in the screenshot)... and I don't think you can use the default profile anyway.  Create a new profile in your browser first.  You'd want to use that one, or just don't specify one.  (don't use any options)

Comment: thanks for replay pcalkins.as you mentioned above i tried all the possible ways still it is working and my local chrome browser was opening fine but next actions was not performed. etc:-like its not entering url and above mentioned exception

Answer (score 0):

Try removing o.setBrowserVersion("120.0.6099.71") and run the code.

Comment: thanks for the reply Aniket Khaire. i tried removing o.setBrowserVersion("120.0.6099.71"); Still iam getting some exception again, can you please help me..

Answer (score 0):

new additional argument
addArguments('--remote-debugging-pipe')

Comment: thanx for ur response.., again iam getting same issue can please help.. org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.

Comment: ChromeOptions o=new ChromeOptions();
        o.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\Hemadri Reddy\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\User Data");
        o.addArguments("--remote-debugging-pipe");
//        o.setBrowserVersion("120.0.6099.71");
        WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver(o);
        d.get("https://tester.com");
this is the code i have used at this time, again iam getting same issue again